# Using SSIS, how to insert new data from Excel sheet into my existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have imported some data from Excel file into my SQL Server table using SSIS. As because it's a report of profit & loss statement it has a header named as Trading Name, address fiscal year etc.

In SSIS, I've used OLE DB Source and used the query like

```
Select * from [Sheet1$A10:E]
```

so the data has been picked up. But U need to insert the trading Name and fiscal year information along with the others data like

```
Trader FYear AccNo AccName   July        August     September
 a      2014 4-0000 In          
 a      2014 4-0500 Ad      $4,514.06   $4,521.23   $4,296.62
 a      2014 4-1000 Me      $37,085.78  $35,676.20  $36,150.87
 a      2014 4-1300 Ro      $11,876.20  $10,956.70  $11,819.04
 a      2014 4-2000 Gr      $57,540.76  $52,978.63  $54,272.24
```

I can pick up the trader and FYear from that Excel sheet by using OLE DB Source and SQL is

```
select * from [Sheet1$a1:a8]
```

and using conditional split I can separate them. But I don't actually know how to insert that data to each column of that table like above.

One more thing, if i write the query like

```
insert into tblA(Trader, FYear, AccNo, AccName, July, August, September)
   select 
      'a', '2014', tblB.AccNo, tblB.AccName, 
      tblB.July, tblB.August, tblB.September;
```

then, it works in SQL Server table but could anyone help me to insert those two columns with that data like above table? Thanks anyway

![enter image description here][1]

```
Trading Name(a)                                                 
Address1                                                    
Address2                                                    


Profit & Loss Statement                                                 
Fiscal Year(2014)                                                   


AccNo    AccName               July       August    September
4-0000  In          
4-0500  Ad                    $4,514.06     $4,521.23   $4,296.62
4-1000  Me                    $37,085.78    $35,676.20  $36,150.87
4-1300  Ro                    $11,876.20    $10,956.70  $11,819.04
4-2000  Gr                    $57,540.76    $52,978.63  $54,272.24
4-3500  B                     $0.00         $0.00       $0.00
4-4000  P                     $3,576.76     $4,110.66   $2,208.31
4-5000  Be                    $19,559.94    $17,926.14  $18,260.71
4-6000  Tu                    $13,471.97    $15,042.04  $13,150.06
4-8900  Re                    $3,500.00     $0.00       $0.00
    Total Income              $151,125.47   $141,211.60 $140,157.85

5-0000  Cost of Sales           

    Gross Profit            $151,125.47 $141,211.60 $140,157.85

6-0000  Expenses            
6-1000  General & Administrative Exp            
6-1050  Accounting Fees            $0.00    $0.00   $270.00
6-1200  Bank Charges              $11.20    $11.20  $14.99
```

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server---10-steps-to-follow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > i can pick up the trader and FYear from that excel sheet by using OLE DB Source but i don't actually know how to insert that data to each column of that table like above

Use your existing method to populate two SSIS variables with the trader and FYYear at the start. Then subsequently in your data flow use a derived column transform and insert the variable value in as an additional column.

Based on the image you sent:

[image]

1. Delete everything except the *first* ForEachLoop container and its contents
2. Inside this ForEachLoop container add an execute SQL task which runs `select * from [Sheet1$a1:a1]`. This should get the Fiscal Year (if it's in that cell) and you should be able to load that result into a single string variable (which you need to create beforehand). You need to set it up as *ResultSet=SingleRow* and you need to map the resultset area. You do not need to use the parameter mapping area

See here more more info on how to load a variable from a single row result: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/

3. Now in your existing Excel Data Source data flow, add a derived column transformation and include these string variables as extra columns that will be inserted into the table

Comment: Thanks for your Answer however when i was trying to do your way by using derived column, it didn't work as these was no unique key to link each other. Actually, i am suffering a lot as i have no accessibility user access to show my SSIS hierarchy in  here, so you might be get confused. Sorry, for late reply.

Comment: You don't need a unique key. Every sheet has a fixed Trade and FYear right? Derive it at the start and provide it as a constant in the data flow. We must be misunderstanding each other

Comment: You know what i did at last? I dynamically linked my source excel file as i have multiple file. Then using conditional split i just divided my whole data (AccNo,AccName, July,August,September) in one side and the other side i    picked up (tradingName) as one destination and fiscalPeriod in another destination. Then i am running EXECUTE SQL Task and write the sql command like insert into tblA(Trader, FYear, AccNo, AccName, July, August, September) select  tblC.Trader, tblD.FY, tblB.AccNo, tblB.AccName, tblB.July, tblB.August, tblB.September from tblB, tblC, tblD.

Comment: it works for a fixed fiscal period but i have several fiscal year in several excel file. That's why i'm using foreach loop in control flow. As a result, the the whole data, i'm getting through but being inserted like

Comment: it works for a fixed fiscal period but i have several fiscal year in several excel file. That's why i'm using foreach loop in control flow. As a result, the the whole data, i'm getting through but being inserted differently like (row1: trader1 null null ... row2: null 2014 null .... row3: null null  4-0500 Ad                    $4,514.06     $4,521.23 $4,296.62 ..) which are logical as i'm not using any inner join. for this i'm trying to save trader, fiscal year and (account no, accountName, july...) in together after differentiating by using Conditional split. i think your Derived Column

Comment: would be helpful but really i dont know how to do this ? I tried many times but failed. Could you help me please?

Comment: So you have managed to use the For Each loop to work through different files right? Can you confirm that each **sheet** in each file has ONE or MANY trading name / fiscal years?

Comment: Each Sheet in each file has one Trading name and one fiscal year. Thanks for your response. I was getting frustrated

Comment: My hierarchy is ExcelSource -> Conditional Split -> one side OLE Destination (this destination i saved (AccNo,AccName, July,August,September) to a SQL Server Table)  -> other side another Conditional Split -> one side i've got trader -> Saved in RecordSet Destination, another side i've got Fiscal Year -> Saved in another RecordSet Destination. BUT, I think, need to save all these in one table or recordsetDestination. is it possible anyway ?

Comment: How do you currently extract the Fiscal Year ad Trading from the sheet in inside your For Each? Do you have that part working?

Comment: In control flow, my hierarchy is Foreach Loop container (inside container i passed my data flow task) -> execute sql task (insert into tblA(AccNo, AccName, July, August, September) select AccNo, AccName, July, August, September from tblB) -> ForEach loop (inside container i am running SQL TASK for FiscalYear (Update tblA Set FiscalYear=?) passing parameter of RecordsetDestination which i called in Data Flow) -> ForEach loop (inside container i am running SQL TASK for Trader (Update tblA Set Trader=?) passing parameter of RecordsetDestination which i called in Data Flow).

Comment: How are you currently extracting `Fiscal Year` and `Trading Name` from the sheet? Are you doing a select on the sheet and filtering it down to get the cells you need? **If you can't answer this I won't be able to help any further**

Comment: This system works for only one fiscal year. But i have 2 files inside folder so 2 fiscal year, 1 trader, and 18x2=36 Data from 2 files. The ForEach for Fiscal year and trader mainly extracted last position of the recordset. It is not looping through actually, that's why last files fiscal year is being updated.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I added the last two foreach loop because i was added two recordset destination and there were two variables. Your 2nd and 3rd step you asked for what i am not able to do myself without your help.

Comment: Thats why I keep asking!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! How are you retrieving those values from the sheet right now? You need to adapt that method to load the values into a variable. Let me see if I can find an example online.

Comment: I have told you previously, may be my English is not good that's why you are not getting that. I am saying it again, i am using conditional split and using some silly condition i differentiate my fiscal year and trader and rest of the data.  Did you see my data flow that i recently answered. I can't see it as may be i am new in here that's why.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand but I think I do now. I've changed my answer again. See if that works (it's really a theory - loading data out of Excel is suprisingly difficult)

Comment: I don't know how to appreciate you however Thanks aaaaaaaaaaa lot ! It worked at last and of course your direction helped me huge though i have done changing a bit. At a moment, i was so frustrated that i thought that i would not able to do it. People may think its a simple task but for me, its big big job as because i  had been trying to get this output last four weeks continuously. Really really you are so helpful. I'm so happy for you. Unfortunately, i've no power to vote you but i'll remember you, Nick!

Comment: I'm very happy I could help :) If the answer helped you just tick it as correct. We both learnt something because I wasn't certain this approach would work and now you have taken the time to prove it.

Comment: I've got another issue that i want to retrieve some data like 'record' from the following file 'D:\folder one\folder2\folder3\record 2014 company.xlsx' which is stored in a variable. i'm sure that i have to use Substring and findstring but it is not being happened for me. could you do that for me please?